# SqlException "Invalid User Account" thrown by application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, sqlclient

I've developed a website which connects to a SQL Server 2012 instance.  This works fine in my development environment.  However, when trying to deploy to a production environment, the page returns the following error:

> Server Error in "/theapp" Application.
>   Invalid User Account
>   Description: an unhandled exception occured during the execution of the current web request.  Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code
>   Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid User Account

[screen shot of stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL4IG.png)

I am struggling to find any documentation regarding this on the Internet; is there anyone who might know where I can start looking for a resolution?

Thanks kindly!

**Update (4/7/2016 @ 3:18pm)**: The service account is a domain account which has correct permissions on the database.  In addition, the same account is used by another website to connect to the same database, and this works fine.

**Update (5/7/2016 @ 10:16am)**: The only thing I can think of is something to do with the usage of LINQ to SQL queries within the application.  Does this sound like a possible cause?

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the credentials you are using to connect to sql server are incorrect.

Make sure you are using correct credential viz. user name and password in your connection string. You can check it by logging on to sql server instance from these credentials.

If you are using integrated security, i.e. windows authentication, verify if the user have given permission on sql.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I can confirm that the account I'm using has permissions on the SQL database, as I was able to login directly using these credentials in SQL Server Management Studio.  In addition, a different website we have also runs correctly using this same account.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass Windows authentication through a website, the identity of your app pool is the user credentials that are supplied. Be sure your app pool for the site is set to use the same user as you expect in the identity of the app pool. Also, be sure integrated security is set to SSPI, not true, in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes, I'm using a domain account as the Application Pool Identity, and this account has permissions granted to the SQL Server database.  In fact, I've used multiple known-good accounts, all still present the same error (but I've verified they all do work when I use them on a different application with a different app pool).  In addition, I'm making sure to use "Integrated Security=SSPI" in my web.config.